# how to calculate balance from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like that below:

tbl_deposit:

```
id,date,client_id,deposit
```

tbl_expense:

```
id date,client_id,expense
```

I want to see the result when `where client_id=1`

like this:

```
date---------deposit-expense-balance  
2018-12-10---500-----0-------500 
2018-12-10---0-------200-----300 
2018-12-11---400-----100-----600  
2018-12-12---0-------500-----100
```

Comment: Provide ddl's and sample data.

Comment: is there an opening balance?  What MySQL version?

Comment: Suggest using [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75432/calculating-a-running-balance-to-store-with-transactions) as a base, `tbl_deposit` and `tbl_expense` will be `UNION`ed to a transaction like table initially.

Comment: Why first 2 records in desured output having the same date are not combined into one record whereas third record is combined one?

Comment: @Akina, due to client 'form is two . so i need to store two tables.

Comment: No. I don't ask about teables, I ask about your "like this" sample poutput. First two records have `date = '2018-12-10'`. Why they are not combined to one record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For onу specified client:

```
SELECT `date`, deposit, expense, @temp := @temp + deposit - expense balance
FROM (
SELECT `date`, SUM(deposit) deposit, SUM(expense) expense
FROM ( SELECT `date`, deposit, 0 expense
       FROM tbl_deposit
       WHERE client_id=1
     UNION ALL
       SELECT `date`, 0, expense
       FROM tbl_expense 
       WHERE client_id=1
     ) total
GROUP BY `date`
) summarized, 
( SELECT @temp := 0 ) variable
ORDER BY `date`;
```

For all clients:

```
SELECT `date`, deposit, expense, 
       @temp := CASE WHEN @client_id = client_id THEN @temp ELSE 0 END + deposit - expense balance, 
       @client_id := client_id client_id
FROM ( SELECT client_id, `date`, SUM(deposit) deposit, SUM(expense) expense
       FROM ( SELECT client_id, `date`, deposit, 0 expense
              FROM tbl_deposit
            UNION ALL
              SELECT client_id, `date`, 0, expense
              FROM tbl_expense 
            ) total
       GROUP BY client_id, `date`
     ) summarized, 
     ( SELECT @temp := 0, @client_id := 0 ) variable
ORDER BY client_id, `date`;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d6218e378493871303a650f6bcf29a99)

Comment: it works fine for sum(deposit) and sum(expense). But it is not working for balance .please see screenshot https://imgur.com/a/U5RSd5w

Comment: sorry again. it is not working for balance. Lets have a look table. see the screenshot https://imgur.com/a/8sVjRDW

Comment: We do not heal by photos. Use fiddle always.

Comment: have a look two tables like that  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1ce5f/1/0  and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/038b65/1/0

Comment: @Faruk The answer edited. The fiddle edited using your sources. PS. Try do not use sqlfiddle - it is sometimes unoperable...

Comment: by the by, I want to learn mysql sql complex join query. how can I learn complex query? can you help me to  learn source tutorial?

Comment: Documentation. Practical experience. Exploring ready-made solutions and tricks used in them. Plus logic and accuracy. And array-based way of thinking, not iterations-based. Tutorial - I don't know them in english, because it is not my native...